# How can I tell if a function argument is given as an expression without evaluating it?

Tags: r, expression, eval

Here is a simple function that takes an expression as an argument.

```
f <- function(expr) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  eval(expr)
}
```

(In practice, I also need to manipulate the expression a little in the function and may evaluate the expression in some other environment where it is meaningful)

It works fine when we call

```
f(1+1)
```

by directly supplying an unevaluated argument.

However, I need `f` to also work like when I supply an explicitly defined expression outside, for example,

```
q <- quote(1+1)
f(q)
```

`f(expr)` needs to avoid substitute `expr` and return the value of the expression. However, the code above does not work because it results in the expression itself rather than 2.

So the question is: How can I tell if an argument is given as an expression without evaluating it in the current environment?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you'd like to check if you're passed a "name" rather than a "call"

```
f <- function(expr) {
    expr <- substitute(expr)
    if(is.name(expr)) {
        expr <- eval(expr, parent.frame())
    }
    eval(expr)
}


f(1+1)
# [1] 2

q<-quote(1+1)
f(q)
# [1] 2
```

Comment: I like this much cleaner approach. +1

Comment: Why can't we just do: `f <- function(expr) {expr <- substitute(expr);
 eval(expr, parent.frame())}` (excude the single line function as it's in comments)?

Comment: @TylerRinker That method would certainly evaluate the expression correctly, I do the extra step because the OP said they may want to modify the expression. This way after the if statement, you should be able to modify the the code that will be eval'ed.

Comment: Tiny nit pick: you should never use `==` with class since it might return multiple values (also I think it's confusing when the object isn't S3). Here you can use `is.name`

Comment: Also this will fail if you supply the quoted object directly. Basically it's a bad idea to try and make a function do both standard and non standard eval.

Comment: Good points @hadley. I've updated the example. And I agree it's not a good idea to try to do both. Clearly KunRen is trying to do some odd stuff with evaluation based on recent questions.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably better ways but here's one approach:

```
f <- function(expr) {
    mess <- suppressWarnings(try(expr, silent = TRUE))
    if (inherits(mess, "try-error")) {
        expr <- substitute(expr)
    }

    eval(expr)
}

f(1+1)
## [1] 2

q <- quote(1+1)
f(q)
## [1] 2
```

This bit extends it to character vectors:

```
f <- function(expr) {
    mess <- suppressWarnings(try(expr, silent = TRUE))
    if (inherits(mess, "try-error")) {
        expr <- substitute(expr)
    }

    if (is.character(expr)) return(eval(parse(text=expr)))
    eval(expr)
}

f("1 + 1")
## [1] 2
```

I'd reccomend reading this bit [HERE](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html) from Hadley's Advanced R